# Height of a binary tree: why is this solution not passing 2/6 test cases in hackerrank?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, testcase

Wrote a recursive solution for the height of a binary search tree that uses in-order traversal.

Every time the function reaches a "null" node (the end of a line), it resets the variable called "numLevels". Every time the method reaches the end of a line, if numLevels > finalVar, then finalVar becomes numLevels.

This is my solution:

```
 static int finalVar= 0;
    static int numLevels= 0; 
    
    public static int height(Node root) {
        // traverse (in order), ml++ with every recursive call, reset when node == null
        findHeight(root);
        
        if (finalVar-1 == 1) return 0;  // special case defined in instructions
        else{
              return finalVar-1;
        }
    }
    
    public static void findHeight(Node node){
        numLevels++;       // every time we recursive call, we add
        
        if (node == null){
            if (numLevels > finalVar){
                finalVar=numLevels;
            }
            numLevels=0;
            return;
        }
        findHeight(node.left);
        findHeight(node.right);
    }
```

and these are the two test cases that it isn't passing:
[image: test case 1]

and:
[image]

all the other test cases are passing. Can anyone spot the reason it's not working? :( thanks!

Comment: Your recursive method should return a value. You don't need a static variable for this.

Answer (score 3):

Just spitballing, but wouldn't setting numLevels to 0 also reset it for the other branch? Because remember that your recursive call goes all the way down the furthest left branch, then the branch to the right of the last left. numLevels at that time is 0, which would never be bigger than the other branch.

Since you're making a helper function anyways, there is no reason to have static variables. Just pass along the current max, and the count, and then do everything the same. That way, your current depth is "thread safe" in respect to your recursive depth.

Comment: makes sense!! thank you! had to use static variables though since static methods can only reference static variables :( completely agree with the fact that the numLevels is only correctly counting the levels in the furthest left branch but I don't know when I would reset numLevels if not there?

Comment: @SomeoneLearning17 The point would be to not use static variables, and pass the data along as an argument. So your new function signature would be:

public static void findHeight(Node node, int depth, int maxDepth);

To answer your second question, consider if you even need to "set" it to 0 manually? When you recursion escapes, you're really going up a node right? If you go down, you add 1 to depth. I'm sure you can extrapolate from there.